# How to use puppet to configure the docker daemon on service start up

Tags: docker, configuration, config, puppet

I am using puppet to configure a docker instance. Below is a code snippet that starts docker on the instance.

```
  service { 'docker':
    ensure   => running,
    name     => 'docker',
    provider => 'systemd',
    enable   => true,
    require  => [ File['/root/.docker/config.json'], File['/etc/sysconfig/docker'], Package['docker-ce'] ]
  }
```

According to the docker documentation, you can pass in arguments to set different configurations when starting the docker daemon.

for example `dockerd --icc=false` will start docker and apply the config change for `icc`.

I know I can add config changes to a daemon.json file and have docker pick that up, but I want to figure out how to make the config changes live in the puppet code.

So how can I specify config changes like --icc=false when starting docker the way I am in the puppet code above??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So how can I specify config changes like --icc=false when starting docker the way I am in the puppet code above??

You can't.  The resource declaration you present ensures that the Docker daemon is running, but it does not directly execute `dockerd`, and therefore provides no mechanism for passing arguments to the daemon binary.  It does *specifically* manage the daemon via `systemd`, however, so you could do what you describe by having Puppet manage the corresponding systemd unit file, but that's not meaningfully different than managing `daemon.json` (via Puppet) instead.

It is absolutely normal, by the way, to manage the configuration (file) of a service and the run state of that service via different Puppet resources.  Usually one also manages the package providing the service, too, wrapping all that up into a module.  In fact, there are several pre-built Docker modules available already, including [one built and maintained by Puppet, Inc., itself](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/docker).